# Select min value from each category

Tags: sql

I have a table with wines- name, type, price and I'm trying to select the cheapest wine from each type.

I have this query to get the min price of each category:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wine.WineType, MIN(wine.Price) OVER(PARTITION BY wine.WineType) as MinPrice
FROM wine;
```

Which outputs:

[image: table with of distinct wine types on the left and minimum price for each type on the right]

My failed attempt to add wine name to the cheapest price looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wine.WineType, MIN(wine.Price) OVER(PARTITION BY wine.WineType),
(SELECT wine.WineName 
FROM wine 
WHERE wine.Price = (SELECT MIN(wine.Price) OVER(PARTITION BY wine.WineType))
FROM wine;
```

How can I connect the name field to each of the output rows?

Comment: Please *only* tag the RDBMS you are **really** using. I have removed the conflicting tags; you need to [edit] your question to add the correct one.

Comment: What if there are multiple wines that all have the same price?

Comment: You have probably more tan one 'wine name' per 'type', which one(s) do you want to print?

Comment: Pinot Nior -> Pinot Noir

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

```
select w.*
from wine w
where w.price = (select min(w2.price) from wine w2 where w.winetype = w2.winetype);
```

With an index on `wine(winetype, price)` is this is often the fastest method.

Note that window functions are not needed for this query at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK` to order the Wines and then select the least one.

```
 ; With OrderedWines AS (
    SELECT WineName
         , Price AS CheapestPrice 
         , WineType
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WineType ORDER BY Price) AS PriceOrder
    FROM wine 
)
SELECT * 
FROM OrderedWines
WHERE PriceOrder = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems weird you are using a window function to get all rows with an added aggregation value only to remove most of them with `DISTINCT`. Why do you use a window function at all? Use plain aggregation instead. Your original query would just be:

```
select winetype, min(price) as minprice
from wine
group by winetype;
```

For the ranking where you really want to show rows (wines), you can use window functions. `RANK` or`DENSE RANK` preferedly. Or use the query above as a subquery (provided your DBMS allows this syntax; some fail to do so):

```
select *
from wine
where (winetype, price) in
(
  select winetype, min(price)
  from wine
  group by winetype
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       WineType, 
       MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY WineType) AS MinPrice,
       FIRST_VALUE(WineName) OVER (PARTITION BY WineType ORDER BY Price) AS WineName
FROM wine;
```

Comment: thank you sql wizard, this works exactly as I wanted :)

Comment: @Wizard fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.